# Unable to Deserialize XML document (Inner Exception: <ArrayOfString xmlns ="> was not expected)

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have written a serialization routine that takes 3 separate streams and serializes the string data from three different arrays into respective XML files.
However, upon deserialization, I encounter an exception:

ArrayOfString xmlns was not expected ........

My knowledge of XML in general is limited at the moment, but I know that I have a particular declaration at the top of my XML file, which I am supposing is giving the deserialization trouble:

Here is a bit of the deserialization code:

```
        // Create a string array to hold the deserialized data.
        string[] stringArray = new string[10];

        // Locate the target file path of the XML files storing the task information. 
        string taskCategoryFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString() + "taskCategory.txt";
       try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(taskCategoryFilePath))
            {
                // Declare a new Xml Document and Serializer object.
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));

                // Attempt to assign the deserialized data to a string array.
                stringArray = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error loading the tasks:" + ex.ToString());
        }     
    }
```

I reckon I can either remove the offending XML declaration from my file, either through some XML attribute or property, or I can serialize the data in such a way that omits the offending part of the declaration. How I do that is where I am stuck- or perhaps it's a different problem all together!

EDIT: Here is the serialization routine, in case it may be helpful:

```
        // Create 3 seperate memory streams, one for each
        // file destination of the tasks.
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream3 = new MemoryStream();

        // Create an XML document and serializer object.
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.TasksBody.GetType());

        // Loop through this functionality 3 times,
        // recursively serializing task category, name and body arrays.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                // Switch-Case through index values, writing to each respective stream for
                // the relevant task content.
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        serializer.Serialize(stream1, this.TasksCategory);
                        stream1.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream1);
                            break;
                    case 1:
                        serializer.Serialize(stream2, this.TaskName);
                        stream2.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream2);
                break;
                    case 2:
                        serializer.Serialize(stream3, this.TasksBody);
                        stream3.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream3);
                break;
                }

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskCategoryFilePath);
                        stream1.Flush();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskNameFilePath);
                        stream2.Flush();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskBodyFilePath);
                        stream3.Flush();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Here is an example of the XML output file information:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <string>Songs to learn</string>
 <string>Games to play</string>
```

EDIT: And here also is the inner exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationPrimitiveReader.Read_string()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.DeserializePrimitive(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --

Comment: `I have successfully written a serialization routine`. Not so successful. Sorry, I just had to say it... :-)

Comment: Please post sample xml so we can help you.

Comment: @JuanR - The serialization routine that I have written is indeed successful as I have output XML files; I have not included the code for that here as what I need help with is the deserialization functionality.

Comment: Writing a successful serialization routine **includes** being able to "successfully" deserialize it. Otherwise, how do I recover what I just serialized? Anyways, please post a complete, but reduced sample of the xml, not just the fragment where you think the problem is.

Comment: It would also be useful to see the serialization code.

Comment: Oh yeah, please post the full exception stack too.

Comment: @JuanR I suppose you are right. I have editied my question to include both the inner exception and the serialization function, hopefully they will be helpful.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Not happy about the rip-off answer though. Unfortunately, you marked that one accepted.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure which one to accept as they were both correct, but I chose the other gentleman's answer only because I assumed his answer came first as it sat on above your one on the page. If I'm wrong though I'll happily re-mark yours as the accepted.

Comment: Don't sweat it. I had posted my answer first and he chose not to remove his even though I mentioned it to him. It doesn't matter. It's the lack of decency on his part that bothers me. You were able to fix your problem and that's what we are here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your serializer is not of the correct type.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
```

should probably be

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
```

Here is a little demo example

```
string[] foo = { "Bar", "Baz", "Ban" };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
string file = "File.xml";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    serializer.Serialize(sw,foo);
}
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    //serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));  //Uncomment me to see your error message
    var test = serializer.Deserialize(sr);
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just reading this answer after editing my question- will edit my code to see if it works

Comment: Update: Indeed, the this and the other answer were correct, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
```

It should be:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
```

The target object is an `array` of type `string`, not a `string`.

Also, don't constrain the size of the variable:

```
var stringArray = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Seeing this answer also after editing my question- just like the answer above, I'll implement the changes and report if it works. EDIT: Worked! I missed something so simple and was going around in circles for quite a while, thanks a lot!